# How to ensure data persistence in hyperledger fabric if the network is deployed using docker swarm?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have set up a docker swarm cluster having a solo orderer and a docker compose stack deployed on multiple hosts. But whenever the network restarts, all the data is lost(since the services get deleted).
How to ensure data backup and recovery if a new network is started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set volumes inside your docker swarm (stack.yaml), its like docker-compose. Here you have an example:

```
volumes:
    peer0.org1.example.com:
    orderer.example.com:

services:
    orderer.example.com:
       volumes:
          - orderer.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    peer0.org1.example.com:
        volumes:
          - peer0.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
```

This should be inside your stack.yaml with your others configurations.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Is this the only way to persist the blockchain data, even in the production environment?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. But if you have more than one peer, and one lose all data, the peer can recovery it from other peers in the network, only you need to join again to the channel and install all chaincodes.